# Block site if browser not in incognito - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, privacy

I want to block sites like internet banking and accounting systems if browser not in incognito mode (for security reasons, because browser has several plugins).

Is it possible to block opening web site if browser not in incognito mode?

(Best solution that I see is force opening selected sites in incognito, when I enter `mybank.com` browser open incognito window without any extensions and other stuff.)

Comment: There's bound to be a chrome extension that can block a website - you can set it up and by default it won't run in incognito. However it's pretty easy to disable extensions so you might need a more robust solution if it's someone actively trying to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

As quick solution I found chrome plugin BlockSite (or any other for blocking sites) and added sites to blacklist. By default in chrome incognito plugins doesn't work - in normal mode I can't open banking sites, but in incognito they works because plugins not load.